# Multithreading libraries not detected

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, mingw, posix

This is a simple code which I have written to learn multi threaded programming on a Windows 7 OS in eclipse.

```
pthread_mutex_t double_release_001_glb_mutex_;
pthread_mutex_t * double_release_001_glb_mutex = & double_release_001_glb_mutex_;

void double_release_001_glb_mutex_lock () {}
void double_release_001_glb_mutex_unlock () {}

int double_release_001_glb_data = 0;

void * double_release_001_tsk_001 (void * pram)
{

    pthread_mutex_lock (double_release_001_glb_mutex);
    double_release_001_glb_data = (double_release_001_glb_data% 100) + 1;

    pthread_mutex_unlock (double_release_001_glb_mutex);
    return NULL;
}

void double_release_001 ()
{
    pthread_t tid1;
    pthread_mutex_init (double_release_001_glb_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_create (& tid1, NULL, double_release_001_tsk_001, NULL);
    pthread_join (tid1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (double_release_001_glb_mutex);
}

void double_release_001_tskentry_001 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (rand ())
        {
            double_release_001_tsk_001 (NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build it I get an error saying

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'   
undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'       
undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'   
undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'
```

I have included `pthread.h`. Can someone help me out here.

Comment: Linker says it couldn't find `pthread_create`. For gcc you link it with `-lpthread`..do the equivalent for windows version of pthreads.

Comment: Are you specifying the libraries in Linker explicitly?

Comment: C/C++ -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> (MinGW)Linker -> Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this option to the linker: -lpthread